# IBM Websphere v8.5.5.4 : Websocket deployment successful but client not connecting

Tags: java, websocket, websphere, websphere-8, jsr356

I was able to deploy a sample Websocket application in my Liberty profile and it was working as tested. Then, I tried to deploy the same application to real **WAS v8.5.5.4** ( so far I know *WAS 8.5.5.4 has websocket support*). It looks like application was deployed successfully and Web pages are accessible but WEBSOCKET functionality is not working e.g. my web socket client not able to connect with the Server. Some **SystemOut.log** tail in below:

```
[8/14/15 9:45:49:039 EDT] 00000095 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1008I: An attempt is made to start the WebsocketDemo-1_war application. (User ID = defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/debnatp)
[8/14/15 9:45:49:050 EDT] 00000095 CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=WebsocketDemo-1_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=WebsocketDemo-1_war.
[8/14/15 9:45:49:059 EDT] 00000095 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: WebsocketDemo-1_war
[8/14/15 9:45:49:059 EDT] 00000095 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: WebsocketDemo-1_war  Application build level: Unknown
[8/14/15 9:45:49:073 EDT] 00000095 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: WebsocketDemo-1.war.
[8/14/15 9:45:49:081 EDT] 00000095 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/WebsocketDemo
[8/14/15 9:45:49:089 EDT] 00000095 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module null has been bound to default_host[*:9080,*:80,*:9443,*:5060,*:5061,*:443].
[8/14/15 9:45:49:092 EDT] 00000095 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: WebsocketDemo-1_war
[8/14/15 9:45:49:092 EDT] 00000095 CompositionUn A   WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=WebsocketDemo-1_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=WebsocketDemo-1_war started.
[8/14/15 9:45:49:216 EDT] 00000095 SystemOut     O req=get&sessionVariable=com_ibm_ws_inlineMessages
[8/14/15 9:46:14:457 EDT] 00000095 WebContainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /WebsocketDemo/echo has not been defined.
```

Any thought or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For now, only WebSphere Liberty profile supports websockets. Full(aka classic) WebSphere Application Server doesn't support websocket yet. Check this [page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/tpack_websocket.htm?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en).

Support for websockets and Java EE 7 in classic WebSphere Application Server is planned, but not yet available.

If you need websockets functionality you will have to use Liberty Profile or Liberty Core editions.

BTW. WebSphere Liberty is fully supported for production usage. So if you have classic WebSphere 8.5.5 license, you can use Liberty in production instead.